# Typical AWS setup for a PHP application

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am developing a Yii web application. In order to be ready for growth I figured I would give a try to Amazon AWS. I've never used their services. 
My question is what is the typical setup I would need for my application? It seems they have a lot of different services that work together. Which pieces of AWS do I need? How do they connect together?

I will need to run PHP (with Yii). I use MySQL (probably need a cloud version?), some file storage, multiple domain names linked to my app. 
I want to easily grow my ressources as my service becomes popular.

I assume its a pretty standard setup...

Comment: you didn't provide enough information, but Amazon AWS is easily salable so you can go from little and grow your resources as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong, it is not a standard setup. The bits you already know, database, domains, files, but the exact details of how they're set up is widely divergent or not significantly affected by the AWS environment.

Comment: Agreed. AWS is **not** a magic bullet. Rather, they give you a bunch of tools that you will need to piece together in a way that is very specific to *your* application. Just because you can scale to 10k servers with a single command on EC2 doesn't mean that they do the work of making your application deal with that gracefully - that task is left to you.